# Nativescript inner StackLayout

Tags: nativescript

Hello everyone I'm trying to make inner StackLayouts but the second one comes to top of first one so that I can't see the second StackLayout  should I handle with css  if it is how or is there an other way

**Here is my code**

```
<StackLayout orientation="horizontal">
    <StackLayout width="500">
         <GridLayout columns="50, *" rows="*" width="500" height="50" 
         verticalAlignment="top">
               <Label text="Name" row="0" col="0" backgroundColor="red">
               </Label>
               <Label text="Fol" row="0" col="1" class="alignRight" 
               backgroundColor="blue"></Label>
         </GridLayout>
    </StackLayout>

      <StackLayout orientation="horizontal" width="500" height="180"> 
           <Image src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" width="500" left="10" 
           top="30">
           </Image>
      </StackLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

Thank you

Comment: You've set the widths of both the inner StackLayout to 500 - so it assumes your screen is at least 1000 wide - I don't think any phone device is (this is dip) - so NS drops the 2nd SL. I think if you set the width to 50% each and remove the width=500 for the Gridlayout - it should work.   Personal suggestion, this is not an efficiient layout. NS is slow and will get slower if you use layouts like this.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply you said this is not efficient layout, what is the efficient way ? I'm new with nativescript I'd like to hear your way.

Comment: Basically you want to reduce the amount of nested layouts - e.g. you Label with text "Name" is 3 layers in. I didn't look at your layout closely - but I bet it can be done with a single Gridlayout. See if you can do that...

Answer (score 1):

At first I would delete the `widths` to see how the page is displayed. `500` is a very big value. Only large tablets can support that.
As an example at first I would try this :

```
<GridLayout columns="auto, auto">
    <GridLayout col="0" columns="50, *" rows="*" verticalAlignment="top">
          <Label text="Name" row="0" col="0" backgroundColor="red">
          </Label>
          <Label text="Fol" row="0" col="1" class="alignRight" 
               backgroundColor="blue"></Label>
    </GridLayout>
    <Image col="1" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" left="10" op="30">
    </Image>      
</GridLayout>
```

After you see the two parts align horizontally you can start tweaking the widths